# How to use children component methods in react?

Tags: reactjs

In angular I usually do this

```
<ng-container>
  <a (click)="child.sayHi()">click</a>
  <app-children #child>
    <p>children text</p>
  </app-children>
</ng-container>
```

I notice that in react, there is a way like this `ref={this.childRef}`  witch is not as neat as angular, So is there any another way to use children component methods???

Comment: The react ref is basically it. In react you may have noticed that data generally flows in one direction, parent to child, in the form of passed props. Parents reaching into children to do *anything* is very anti-pattern in react. The solution is a process called [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to have the parent hold the data and callback it cares to operate on, and these can be passed on to children via props.

Answer (score 1):

React has a different approach from Angular's.

> React components let you split the UI into independent, reusable pieces, and think about each piece in isolation

This means, parent component need not to call child's method. Parent can however pass down props which triggers methods in Child component, which in turn can update parent state if needed.